# WPF starts from batch file doesn't create folder in APPDATA

Tags: c#, batch-file, log4net

I'm facing a strange problem and I hope that any of you can help me.

I have made a WPF application that will be launched from Lync 2013 custom menu command. 
If I understand well, basically it launches a batch file and then execute my application.

The application has log4net to log errors in the application, and if I launch the application isolated (without being from Lync), a folder is created in the place I say in log4net.config (ProgramData or Roaming folder).

When I launch from Lync application, those folders are not created.

I can simulate this if I create a batch file and in it I call my application....if I do this the folders also are not created.

Does anyone understand this behaviour?

Thanks

===EDIT===

My log4net.config

```
<appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
        <levelMin value="DEBUG" />
        <levelMax value="OFF" />
      </filter>

      <param name="AppendToFile" value="true"/>
      <file value="${AppData}\AppName\Logs\log" />
      <staticLogFileName value="false"/>
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Date" />
      <datePattern value=" yyyy-MM-dd&quot;.txt&quot;"/>

      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger: %message%newline"/>
      </layout>     
    </appender>
```

Comment: Could be a UAC issue. Where are you trying to log to? How does your log4net config look like?

Comment: added config file. I supposed it was also a UAC issue, but if I open command line and open the application by there it works. If I do the same but from a batch file it don't :\

Comment: And your batch file really just calls the wpf application? BTW: Why are you not calling the wpf app from Lync? Why call it via bat file?

Comment: Lync application allows to add menus by registry. Basically on registry I say where my application is (something like this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj945535(v=office.15).aspx) And I think it's Lync that opens the app by executing a bat or something like it.

Comment: Why don't you start the application via Lync and then attach your Visual Studio and debug the logging and see if you can capture an exception or status from the logging method?

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s68z0b3.aspx

Comment: Nothing WPF specific, removed tag.

Answer (score 0):

This was what solved my issue:

replace this:

```
 FileInfo configFileInfo = new FileInfo("log4net.config");
 log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(configFileInfo);
 log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Log));
```

by this:

```
 var log4NetConfigDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.RelativeSearchPath ?? AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
var log4NetConfigFilePath = Path.Combine(log4NetConfigDirectory, "log4net.config");
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(new FileInfo(log4NetConfigFilePath));
log = LogManager.GetLogger(logClass);
```

I think it might be related that the bat file opens a cmd prompt and the log4net.config is not in the folder that the command prompt is opened by default.